# How can I stop nav bar icons from disappearing when hovering over them? using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, nav

The icons in the navbar disappear when hovered over them. How do I stop this and make the icons be bold or something else

```
  <div>
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href=#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></i> LinkedIn</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i><span>
              </span target="_blank"> Download Resume</a></li>
            </ul>
               </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With no example ([jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)) it's hard to say with any certainty. However, try adding this at the end of your CSS file(s): `a:hover {color:red;}`

Seen here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mijopabe/krw7srfc/1/)

It works for me. An example could help see what's going on with your code specifically.